# Java help - Output range with increment of 5

Tags: java

Write a program whose input is two integers, and whose output is the first integer and subsequent increments of 5 as long as the value is less than or equal to the second integer.

```
-15 10
```

the output is:

```
-15 -10 -5 0 5 10
```

> Ex: If the second integer is less than the first as in:

```
20 5
```

the output is:

> Second integer can't be less than the first. For coding simplicity,
> output a space after every integer, including the last.

Here is the code I have gotten so far, however, it is producing an error at the bottom I have an example of the input, my output and what was expected. If anyone has any pointers or can show me updated code it would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int first = in.nextInt(), second = in.nextInt();
        if (first > second) {
            System.out.println("Second integer can't be less than the first.");
        } else {
            while (first <= second) {
                System.out.print(first + " ");
                first += 10;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
   }
}
```

Here's what kind of error it is showing:

Input

```
-15 10
```

Your output

```
-15 -5 5
```

Expected output

```
-15 -10 -5 0 5 10
```

Comment: Your increment is wrong. Change it to `first += 5;`

Comment: Thank you so much! It blows my mind how I manage to reread these things and still dont catch them!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `range` function from `IntStream`:

```
IntStream.range(-15, 10).filter(x -> x % 5 == 0);
```

As suggested by MC Emperor, there also is a faster solution:

```
IntStream.iterate(-15, i -> i + 5).limit((10+15)/5);

/**
 * The algorithm is as follows:
 * iterate(start, i -> i + step).limit((stop-start)/step)
 */
```

Comment: You shouldn't do it like that. `range` always increments by 1, so you're dropping 80% of the values you programmed it to be created. You should use `IntStream.iterate` instead.

Comment: Edited to add your comment in it